# Auto deployment for Microsoft 365 Apps update fails with error code 0x87D20417 - SCCM

Tags: sccm

Our ADR for the latest Microsoft 365 Apps fails with error code 0x87D20417. The update in question is:

Microsoft 365 Apps Update - Monthly Enterprise Channel Version 2008 for x64 based Edition
Microsoft 365 Apps Update - Monthly Enterprise Channel Version 2008 for x64 based Edition

The ruleengine.log states the following:

Failed to download the update content with ID 16933834 from internet. Error = 13875 SMS_RULE_ENGINE Failed to download ContentID 16933834 for UpdateID 16996246. Error code = 13875 SMS_RULE_ENGINE
Failed to download the update content with ID 16933835 from internet. Error = 13875 SMS_RULE_ENGINE
Failed to download ContentID 16933835 for UpdateID 16996248. Error code = 13875 SMS_RULE_ENGINE
Failed to download any update   SMS_RULE_ENGINE
Failed to download update contents. SMS_RULE_ENGINE

I've tried to search for a solution and so far I haven't been able to find out a fix for it. Some are saying it has something to do with certificates, others say with file permissions.

This rule has worked without any issues in the past.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a known issue with the 2020-10 update. Uninstall the October update then reboot

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136944/failed-to-download-content-id-error-invalid-certif.html